# is my solution correct or not? limit to zero rational

Tags: limits

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x}\right)$

my solution

$\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}\right)$ $=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{0+1}+0}\right)$

$=1$

Comment: is it $1$ or $0.5$ ?

Comment: There are a couple of errors. For one, the $x$ in the numerator should have divided out with the $x$ in the denominator, so the numerator is $1$. Then, the "$+1$" in the denominator was mysteriously replaced with "$+0$". The final answer should indeed be $\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: did you divide each term on $x$ ? why you get $1$ instead of $0$ ? I mean is it $\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$

Comment: If $x\neq 0$ division by $x$ is posible, also $\frac{x}{x}=1$, then:
$$\frac{x}{x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}=\frac{x}{x}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{ x+1}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}$$
Why do you think it must be $0$ instead $1$ if we are dividing?

Answer (score 2):

the right result must be $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}$$ and the searched limit is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: did you divide each term on $x$ ? why you get $1$ instead of $0$ ? I mean is it $\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean